# C# Generics: Simplifying method declaration by deduplication

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, methods, .net-7.0

I am building a request execution system that follows a generic response style. The current implementation feels needlessly verbose, in that I specify the request body model (`REQ`) twice:

```cs
var wrappedRequest = new Request<REQ>(...); // omitted for brevity

IRequestExecutionResult<Request<REQ>, REQ> result = await exec.ExecuteAsync<Request<REQ>, REQ>(wrappedRequest);
```

This is achieved with the following method definition on an interface:

```cs
ValueTask<IRequestExecutionResult<T, O>> ExecuteAsync<T, O>(T request, CancellationToken cancel = default) where T : IRequest<O>;
```

I am targeting latest .NET (7). Is there a way to simplify the generic method signature so I only need to specify the request type, and pull the body type off that?

Goal:

```cs
IRequestExecutionResult<Request<REQ>> result = await exec.ExecuteAsync<Request<REQ>>(wrappedRequest);
```

Comment: Any reason not to declare your method as `ValueTask<IRequestExecutionResult<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRequest<T> request, CancellationToken cancel = default)` ?

Comment: @JonasH Stared too far into the generic soup, I suppose. That works as intended, can you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider just removing one layer of generics and write it as:

```
ValueTask<IRequestExecutionResult<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRequest<T> request, CancellationToken cancel = default)
```

This should help with type inference . It is somewhat common to go a bit overboard with generics, and this can lead to issues with method resolution, type inference etc.